# Scrolling Issue with Multiple RecyclerViews in an XML

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, scrollview

Using `multiple` *RecyclerView* in an xml, first two RecyclerViews (Horizontal) and third RecyclerView (Vertical)

As you can see in below screenshot, Whenever, I do Scrolling it scrolls third RecyclerView only not both the RecyclerView(s) those I am using on top of that one

Whereas, I want to scroll all these RecyclerView, If I do scrolling (Scroll Up or Scroll Down)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you applied `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` for recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to extend listview to support custom scrolling by :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ParallaxRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {


    private State state;
    private Recycler recycler;

    public ParallaxRecyclerView(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }

    public ParallaxRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs,0);
    }

    public ParallaxRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        Field fieldState = null;
        Field fieldRecycler = null;
        try {
            fieldState = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mState");
            fieldState.setAccessible(true);
            state = (State) fieldState.get(this);

            fieldRecycler = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mRecycler");
            fieldRecycler.setAccessible(true);
            recycler = (Recycler)fieldRecycler.get(this);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx){
        getLayoutManager().scrollHorizontallyBy(dx,recycler,state);
    }

    public void scrollVerticallyBy(int dy){
        getLayoutManager().scrollVerticallyBy(dy,recycler,state);
    }
}
```

Then add a scroll listnener to your top recyclerview and pass the scroll delta value to

`scrollHorizontallyBy`

For example:

```
topRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
...
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
parallaxRecyclerView.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx);
parallaxRecyclerView.scrollVerticallyBy(dy);
}
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best and easiest solution, I just copied everything inside **ScrollView** and used `height` as *wrap_content* for the *third* and Vertical **RecyclerView**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

......

</ScrollView>
```

And updated version of a *library* in `gradle` file :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```